# My program produces print statement infinity in a loop. Don't know how to fix it

Tags: python, loops, boolean

So I'm trying to learn Python and I have written a program that is essentially designed to play a game with the user and a computer.

This game's mechanics are:

There are two players: the  user and the computer, who alternate turns until    one of them reaches 100 points or higher.

• The user is always the first player.

• If any player reaches 100 points or more at the end of their turn, the game ends immediately and the other player does not get another turn.

• One turn consists of the following: the player rolls a 6-sided die.
      o If they roll    a   1,  they    score   1   point   and their   turn    is  over.   Even    if  a   player  has 
accumulated points  from    previous    rolls,  if  they    roll    a   1,  their   score   for that    turn    will    be  1   point   and their   turn    is  over.

o If   they    roll    any other   number, the roll    score   is  added   to  the turn    total.

o Then, they    have    the option  to  continue    rolling or  to  hold.   There   is  no  restriction on  how many    times   a   player  can roll    in  a   turn.

• Holding:  if  a   player  holds,  they    score   their   current turn    total   and their   turn ends.  If, 
for example,    a   player  rolled  a   3,  4,  and 2,  then    decides to  hold,   they    score   9   points.

• If    the player  is  the user,   they    are given   the option  as  to  whether they    would   like    to
continue    rolling or  hold    after   each    time    they    roll    the die and do  not get a   1.

• If    the player  is  the computer,   they    will    always  continue    rolling until   their   turn    total
reaches the value   10  or  higher.

**The problem with the code is it produces an infinite print statement when the code runs. I worked it down to the Boolean statement in the main function where I set is_user_turn = True. I have sorted through the code but there is something I am not seeing and need help fixing it.**

Here is the code:

```
import random

def welcome():
    print("Welcome to Jeopordy")

def print_current_player(is_user_turn):

    if (is_user_turn == True):
        print("It is now human's turn")
    if (is_user_turn == False):
        print("It is now computer's turn")

def roll_die():

    roll = random(1,6)
    return roll

 def take_turn(is_user_turn,Computer_Hold):

    turn_total = 0

    if(is_user_turn == True):
        while(is_user_turn == True):
            roll = roll_die()

        if(roll == 1):
            return 1
        turn_total = turn_total + roll
        print("Your turn total is 1")
        is_user_turn = False

    else:
        print("You rolled a ",roll)
        turn_total = turn_total + roll
        print("Your turn total is ",turn_total)
        play = input("Do you want to roll gain (Y/N)?")

    if(play == 'N' or play == 'n'):
        is_user_turn = False
        return turn_total

    else:
        is_user_turn == True

    if(is_user_turn == False):

            while(is_user_turn == False):
                roll = roll_die()

            while(turn_total <= Computer_Hold):
                if(roll + turn_total <= Computer_Hold):
                    print("You rolled a ", roll)
                    turn_total = turn_total + roll
                    print("Your turn total is ",turn_total)

    return turn_total

def report_points(userscore,computerscore):
    print("computer: ",computerscore)
    print("user: ",userscore)

def get_next_player(is_user_turn):
    if(is_user_turn == True):
        is_user_turn = False
        return is_user_turn
    else:
        is_user_turn = True
        return is_user_turn

def main():

    Game_End_Points = 100
    Computer_Hold = 10
    is_user_turn = True
    userscore = 0
    computerscore = 0

    welcome()
    while(userscore <= Game_End_Points and computerscore <= Game_End_Points):
        print_current_player(is_user_turn)

        if(get_next_player(is_user_turn) == True):
            userscore = userscore + take_turn(is_user_turn,Computer_Hold)
            report_points(userscore,computerscore)
            get_next_player(is_user_turn)
        elif(get_next_player(is_user_turn) == False):
            computerscore = computerscore + take_turn(is_user_turn,Computer_Hold)
            report_points(userscore,computerscore)
            get_next_player(is_user_turn)

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: We don't need all that background and your entire program. Please trim your question down. You've narrowed the problem down - great! Just post that part!

Comment: You just have a mistake in the indentation of the 8 lines after the while loop. They should be part of the while loop.

Comment: Are you expecting the value of `is_user_turn` in `main()` to ever change, say by the call to `get_next_player`? Because it won't. (BTW, very misleading name for that function considering what it does, as well an a unnecessarily complex implementation of something that's basically a `return not is_user_turn`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is the bug:

```
while(userscore <= Game_End_Points and computerscore <= Game_End_Points):
        print_current_player(is_user_turn)
```

this executes this function infinitely:

```
def print_current_player(is_user_turn):

    if (is_user_turn == True):
        print("It is now human's turn")
    if (is_user_turn == False):
        print("It is now computer's turn")
```

since your function doesn't alter userscore or computerscore, it gets stuck there. That's my hint for now. If you need further help, just ask at comment.
Added Hint: "Indent"
also, just checked your whole code -- seems there are other bugs as well :)

Comment: To my understanding, this function needs to end in order to stop printing this statement. I am not entirely sure how to do this. Maybe I can use a counter?

Comment: Also, fixed the indentation.

Comment: You can use a counter, but that's not what you want to achieve on that line, right? Don't think about ending the loop first but what should be the next step to be executed. That's your first step there.

Comment: Good. You're on the right track. You should now be seeing other bugs :)

Comment: I think the infinite print part is now settled, if you have further questions about your code/bugs, please post a new question. Also, please follow the guidelines as the people above posted.

Comment: Also, just a python tip, rather than doing this: if (is_user_turn == True), you can just do this: if(is_user_turn) since your is_user_turn variable is a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for sure but it looks like this might be causing the loop or is at least going to cause some problems for you:

```
if(play == 'N' or play == 'n'):
    is_user_turn = False
    return turn_total

else:
    is_user_turn == True
```

In the else statement, you are checking that is_user_turn is True instead of assigning it a True value. Looks like it should be `is_user_turn = True`

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

The variable `userscore` will always be less than the `Game_End_Points` and so will be computer score and hence will loop infinitely, use some counter in the loop.

```
while(userscore <= Game_End_Points and computerscore <= Game_End_Points):
    print_current_player(is_user_turn)
    userscore=userscore+10 #something like this
    computerscore+=10
```